# docker-compose: volume problem: path on host created but not populated by container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, persistent-volumes

I have the following docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: bitnami/mongodb:5.0.6
    volumes:
      - "/app/local-data:/data/db"
    env_file: ./db/.env
```

The problem is data does not persist between docker-compose up/down and docker does not seem to use `/app/local-data` even though it creates it.

When I run `docker-compose`, container starts and works naturally. The directory `/app/local-data` **is created by docker**, however Mongodb does not populate it, and no r/w error is being shown on console. This makes me thing a temporary volume is assigned to container instead.. But if that is true then why docker still creates `/app/local-data` and not using it?

Any ideas how can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Docker directives like `volumes:` don't know anything about what's actually running in the image.  That directive creates the specified host and container paths if required, and bind-mounts the host path into the container path.  It's up to the application code to use that directory (or not).

If you look at the [`bitnami/mongodb` Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb) under "Persisting your database", the database is configured to store data in the `/bitnami/mongodb` directory inside the container, and that directory needs to be the second `volumes:` path.  Also note the requirement that the data directory needs to be writable by user ID 1001, which may or may not exist on your host (there's no specific requirement to create it).

```yaml
volumes:
  - "/app/local-data:/bitnami/mongodb"
  #                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```bash
sudo chown -R 1001 /app/local-data
sudo docker-compose up -d
```